# Сохранение прогресса пользователя на сайте

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, ejs

Пользователь регистрируется, заходит на сайт, при входе запись о начале сессии сохраняю в куки браузера.

Например: после того как пользователь входит в кабинет, ему доступно создание заметок.
Например: user1 создал 10 заметок с текстом внутри, после чего вышел из сайта или даже обновил страницу. Другой пользователь войдя в личный кабинет создал уже свои заметки со своим текстом.

С помощью чего я могу запомнить те действия, что пользователь сделал на сайте, чтобы зайдя через 2-3 дня, неважно, хоть банально обновив страницу, эти данные были сохранены на сайте?

Это делается через *Mongodb*?
В разработке использую *MEAN stack*.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же вам нужно использовать базу для хранения каких либо данных на долгосрочной основе! А что качается localStorage или indexedDB - это не вариант, так как данные будут хранится в вашем БРАУЗЕРЕ, в КЭШЕ, а ни где то на локальной машине, и по этому зайдя на сайт с другого устройства или даже с другого браузера, данных которые сохранил пользователь попросту не окажется!
Я бы посоветовал вам использовать связку - mongodb c mongoose библиотекой, настройка этих двух компонентов очень проста и понятна.

Answer (score -2):

Самый простой способ, сохранить в localStorage

```
vhod_knopka.onclick = function(){
    client.send(JSON.stringify({type: "vhod", vhod: vhod_login.value, parol: vhod_parol.value}));
    localStorage.login = vhod_login.value;
    localStorage.parol = vhod_parol.value;
}

client.onopen = function(){
    if(localStorage.login)
        client.send(JSON.stringify({type: "vhod", vhod: localStorage.login, parol: localStorage.parol}));
}
```